# How to preserve default order in Spark dataframe after first order by inside window

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a spark dataframe with columns user_id, C1, f1,f2,f3 . I want to partition/group by `user id` and inside the group I want to maintain the order with respect to `C1`, which I have done successfully, but After the ordering of C1, I want to keep rest of things in default order.

For example.  Below is the dataframe for specific user (filer applied on `user_id == 1`) for example

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+------------------
|User_id | C1          |f1           |f2      | f3              |
+--------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------
|1       | 6420048     |B1           |TC      |19               |
|1       | 21610696    |U0           |PC      |135              |
|1       | 21610700    |U0           |IP      |135              |
|1       | 28975032    |B1           |CU      |20               |
|1       | 46422270    |U3           |CU      |73               |
|1       | 68008129    |U1           |RM      |135              |
|1       | 68008129    |U1           |CM      |135              |
|1       | 68008129    |U1           |CM      |129              |
|1       | 68008129    |U1           |PM      |130              |
|1       | 68023980    |U1           |PM      |129              |
|1       | 68023980    |U1           |CM      |135              |
|1       | 68023980    |U1           |PM      |135              |
|1       | 68023980    |U1           |PM      |130              |
+--------+---------+-------------+--------+---------------------
```

What I am doing right now is,I am partitioning by `user_id` and ordering by `C1`. Window I am using is

```
 Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy('C1')
```

Just to explain my problem, I have added a column `order` like below

```
 df= df.withColumn('order',row_number().over(w))
```

But after the window order gives correct order for C1 (for each user) but with the C1 order isnt preserved as default order, note that for C1 column value `68023980`, it now has f2 sequence `[CM,PM,PM,PM]` but it should have `[PM,CM,PM,PM]` and for C1 `68008129` I have f2 `[PM,CM,PM]` instead of `[CM,PM,PM]`.  Similarly for other columns (f3).

Here is example of current output

```
+--------+---------+-------------+--------+-------+----------
|User_id | C1      |f1           |f2      | f3    | order     |
+--------+-------------+--------+-----------------+-----------
|1       | 6420048 |B1           |TC      |19     |    1      |
|1       | 21610696|U0           |PC      |135    |    2      |
|1       | 21610700|U0           |IP      |135    |    3      |
|1       | 28975032|B1           |CU      |20     |    4      |
|1       | 46422270|U3           |CU      |73     |    5      |
|1       | 68008129|U1           |PM      |129    |    6      |
|1       | 68008129|U1           |CM      |135    |    7      |
|1       | 68008129|U1           |PM      |130    |    8      |
|1       | 68008129|U1           |PM      |135    |    9      |
|1       | 68023980|U1           |CM      |135    |    10     |
|1       | 68023980|U1           |PM      |130    |    11     |
|1       | 68023980|U1           |PM      |129    |    12     |
|1       | 68023980|U1           |PM      |135    |    13     |
+--------+-------------+--------+-----------------+-----------
```

How can i keep default order after being order by C1?

Comment: add monotonically_increasing_id() before applying Window aggregate function.

Comment: Jxc, Thankyou for the comment, Is it different than row_number as order column isnt correct in this case like i mentioned in the answer, any details will be helpful.

Comment: it's not an aggregate function and won't trigger data shuffling. row_number() over a window has to deal with data already shuffled.

Comment: Thank you, I ordered by the montonically increasing it  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guided by @Jxc in comments, I was able to to it with help of adding monotonically_increasing_id() before window operation.

Here is the example

```
df= df.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())
w= Window.partitionBy("user-id").orderBy('C1','idx')
```